# Expand a boolean variable to the string "true" or "false"

Tags: freemarker

In a freemarker template I want to expand a boolean variable to a string like that:

```
<#assign booleanVar = "test".isEmpty() />
state: ${booleanVar} <#-- this throws an exception! -->
```

This is what I want to get as output:

```
state: false
```

The only way I found to reach this goal by now is:

```
state: <#if booleanVar>true<#else>false</#if>
```

Is there a easier way to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
booleanVar?string("true", "false")
```

Although [true/false is default](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/ref_builtins_boolean.html), so

```
booleanVar?string
```

should work fine.

Comment: If I do this I get: "freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression booleanVar$string is undefined".

Comment: I re-read that link... Changed the $ to ? in example.  I don't know freemarker :)

Comment: Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.20, you should use `${booleanVar?c}`. Just writing `${booleanVar?string}` is dangerous, as the default format can be changed. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.20, if you want to print true/false (because you are generating JavaScript or such), write `${booleanVar?c}` (`?c` for "computer format", also used for numbers). `${booleanVar?string}` is dangerous for that, since somebody can set the `boolean_format` setting to `yes,no` or something... (BTW, in that case `${booleanVar}` will work too in 2.3.20, and you get `yes` and `no`.)

See: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_c_boolean